# samba - connect users /home dir to pre-existing /home on a data drive

Tags: server, samba

I am transforming from an existing sambaserver (14.04) to a new install on 18.04. I'll continue to use the existing data partition (on a separate) HD and have installed a new server on a new harddrive. So I need to 'rebuild' the previous server's behaviour as close as possible.

One problem I am facing is related to `/home` directories my users can access via samba. In the old system those where located on the data partition & accessible at `/srv/smb/[user1]`

now on the new install somehow I messed up the `home` folders which are now located in `/home/[user1]`, so I want to use the /homes' folders from the datadrive and am wondering how to tweak it.

Would a symlink like ...

```
mv /home/[user1] /home/[somethingelse]
ln -l /srv/smb/[user1] /home/[user1]
```

... do the job? Or is there a slicker way for achieving that?

---

as requested (dunno how to post that as a comment nicely)

```
~ $ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 186.3G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0   250M  0 part /boot
├─sda3   8:3    0    27G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda5   8:5    0   150G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 698.5G  0 part /srv/smb
└─sdb2   8:18   0  93.1G  0 part
```

Comment: can you show us how your data disk is mounted on your new system? The output of  `lsblk` would help.

Comment: also it would be good to know what path you use for the home directory in the user accounts

Comment: home directories currently are `/home/user1`, `home/user2` (is this what you mean?) @SebastianStark

Comment: what i only need to keep is the content of the previous `/srv/smb/home/user1` as the new `/home/user1` is yet unused.

Comment: Maybe `usermod --move-home -d /srv/smb/ [user1]` (after having changed the name of the pre-existing `/srv/smb/[usr1]`) and then copying the relvant files from the 'old' home to the 'new' home

Comment: so the home directories under `/home` are completely empty currently?

Comment: apart from some `.` files, like `.profile` (which matter I assume), yes, empty. Found a solution in the meantime by the way. Posting below.

Answer (score 0):

so, this is how I could work out that issue

#### 1. change the name of the the `home` of the previous server

`sudo mv /srv/smb/usr1 /srv/smb/usr1_old`

#### 2. move the new home folder of `usr1` to the `/srv/smb/` directory

`sudo usermod -md /srv/smb/usr1/ usr1`

#### 3. check the passwd file (which should show the new directory for usr1)

`cat /etc/passwd | grep usr1`

if that looks good ...

#### 4. copy the content of the old home directory to the new one

`sudo rsync -azvv --ignore-existing /srv/smb/usr1_old/* /srv/smb/usr1/`

a) the `--ignore-existing` option makes sure the `.` files (`.profile` i.e.) in the new home folder (automatically created upon usercreation) are not being overwriten by the `.` files from the old home (not sure whether that really makes a huge difference but still I'd do it this way)
b) I'm sure you can achieve the same result also with `cp`, still I used rsync coz I'm more familiar with that

and ... I'm up'n'runnin' ! I guess it won't hurt to double check access rights are matching the new system (which I did before alreay) also existing  acl's on the old server you may have totally forgot about can cause wuite some headache, so it's worth to look into this as well if running into any problems.

Hope this'll help someone else with the same question. Thanks @Sebastian Stark for the comments above. Somehow they helped me to find my way